# Termux - npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink

Tags: android, npm, termux

Whenever I install a npm-package (like: Puppeteer, Nightmare, Playwright) I get the same *error message*;

But it isn't shown up when I install the npm-packages (axios, http, axios, etc.) almost all minor packages...!

**npm install playwright**:

```js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../playwright/cli.js
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck.editor.node/files/Alexa Kairen || Doruk/node_modules/.bin/playwright
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../playwright/cli.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck.editor.node/files/Alexa Kairen || Doruk/node_modules/.bin/playwright'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../playwright/cli.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck.editor.node/files/Alexa Kairen || Doruk/node_modules/.bin/playwright'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../playwright/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck.editor.node/files/Alexa Kairen || Doruk/node_modules/.bin/playwright'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-08-10T13_22_34_261Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue installing `node_modules` to a USB drive. Using [therocco's answer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/26#issuecomment-206991754) did the job for me.
**INSTALL GLOBAL NPM PACKAGES**
`npm config set unsafe-perm true`

**CLEAN CACHE**
`npm cache clean`

**BYPASS SYMLINK ISSUES**
`npm install --no-bin-links`

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the package with the flag `--no-bin-links`, `npm install --no-bin-links playwright`.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: don't have my android set to English, so the settings could have a different translation.*

1. Hold the Termux app on your phone
2. Click on `App-info`
3. `Rights` or `Permissions`
4. Click on the `Files and media` and grand the permission.
5. try again

Comment: Thereafter another err arises... `npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall link
npm ERR! path /data/data/com.termux/files/home/scraper/_cacache/tmp/8bbe5e2e
npm ERR! dest /data/data/com.termux/files/home/scraper/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/b9/11/6693af8ccd2d926b3162261347f06d31029114534382535f42791326c6f65cd8dada57f1d31da290a1bc9fb353f0edffea544490cd428bcef5f0a3d2a
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 10673:10673`

Comment: And thanks for answering my first question up there... It worked✨✨

Comment: Glad you got some progress, however I have no clue how to fix the new error. I am also new to Termux and haven't used it a lot yet. Good luck.

Comment: Tq............✨

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
npm run d -package=@types/node

"scripts": {
     "d":" npm i $package --no-bin-links && npm run postinstall",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "find node_modules/ -type l -exec rm {} +"
  }
```